# Only hide the window when closing it [Electron]

Tags: javascript, electron

I try to hide my main window so that I hasn't to load again later.
I got the following code:

```
function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})


  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  win.on('closed', (event) => {
    //win = null
    console.log(event);
    event.preventDefault();
    win.hide();
  })
}
```

So that's not working for me, when I close the window I get this error message:
[image]

Can somebody help me? Line 37 is the line with win.hide()

Thank you!

Comment: The error tells you all: the `win` object is already destroyed when you try to hide it.

Comment: But I never destroy it, I (try to) prevent the default action on the closing X button

Comment: Does my answer work for you? @wernersbacher

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use the [`close`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#event-close) event instead of the [`closed`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#event-closed) event.

When the [`closed`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#event-closed) event is fired the window is already closed.

When the [`close`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#event-close) event is fired the window is still open and you can prevent it from closing by using `event.preventDefault();` like this:

```js
win.on('close', function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
});
```

However on MacOS that'll stop you from quitting your app. To allow quitting your app and preventing windows from closing use this code:

```js
// Set a variable when the app is quitting.
var isAppQuitting = false;
app.on('before-quit', function (evt) {
    isAppQuitting = true;
});

win.on('close', function (evt) {
    if (!isAppQuitting) {
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

That'll only stop the window from closing if the app isn't quitting.

Comment: Intercepting the `close event` prevents me from shutting down the application at all - not even by right-clicking the dock icon and selecting `Quit`. How can I distinguish from someone closing the window via the red button in the title bar and someone right-clicking the dock icon and choosing `Quit`?

Comment: @Jan Good point, I've edited my answer, see if that helps :)